# Toggle canvas drawing functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to create a drawing functionality with Fabric.js canvas library and a button to enable/disable the canvas, but whenever I toggle the canvas off, it throws "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node".

```js
const canvasRef = useRef(null);
const canvasContainerRef = useRef(null);
const [drawingEnabled, setDrawingEnabled] = useState(false);

const handleCanvas = () => {
  let canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasRef.current);

  canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
  canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "black";
  canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 2;
  canvas.freeDrawingBrush.strokeLineCap = "round";

  const resizeCanvas = () => {
    canvas.setWidth(canvasContainerRef.current.offsetWidth);
    canvas.setHeight(canvasContainerRef.current.offsetHeight);
    canvas.renderAll();
  };

  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
  resizeCanvas();

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
  };
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (drawingEnabled) {
    handleCanvas();
  }
}, [drawingEnabled]);

const toggleDrawing = () => {
  setDrawingEnabled(!drawingEnabled);
};

return (
    <div ref={canvasContainerRef}>
      {drawingEnabled && <canvas ref={canvasRef} />}
      <button onClick={toggleDrawing}>
        Toggle Drawing
      </button>
    </div>
);
```

How do I fix this, or is there a better way of toggling the drawing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem with the `useEffect` code in your component. When I commented that out, toggling seemed to work fine.